# Optional Promise in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise

I am building a tree of nodes but when I run across a certain value I need to make a rest request to get the child nodes and then build those as well.  The below works when I have the values hard coded in for the `connector.get` request, but when I turn it into a promise the function returns before the promise returns.  How can I refactor this to delay returning until all the promises resolve?

```
 buildDom: (viewObj) ->
    treeElm = document.createElement('div')
    rowContainer = document.createElement('ul')
    view = viewObj.data.options[0]
    i = 0
    while i < view.rows.length
      rowElm = document.createElement('li')
      rowElm.innerHTML = 'Row ' + i
      row = view.rows[i]
      cellContainer = document.createElement('ul')
      j = 0
      while j < row.cells.length
        cell = row.cells[j]
        cellElm = document.createElement('li')
        if cell.view
          cellElm.innerHTML = 'View: ' + cell.view
          if !cell.view?
            connector.get(cell.view).then (res)->
              cellElm.appendChild buildDom(res)
        else if cell.fieldId
          cellElm.innerHTML = 'Field: ' + cell.fieldId
        if cell.displayType != 'NONE'
          cellContainer.appendChild cellElm
        j++
      rowElm.appendChild cellContainer
      rowContainer.appendChild rowElm
      i++
    treeElm.appendChild rowContainer
```

Comment: You always have to `return` (synchronously) before the promise settles (asynchronously). Your only choice is to return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

`cellElm` changes with each iteration of the loop, and so may change during the time that `connector.get` is running, which would lead to appending to the wrong element. Is that what you're seeing? The fix would be to pass `cellElm` to a function so there is a stored copy of it that the `connector.get` call can use. I've inlined such a function below.

```
      if !cell.view?
        ((element) ->
          connector.get(cell.view).then (res)->
            element.appendChild buildDom(res))(cellElm)
```